# Extracting query parameter from requested URL in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-server, url

I would like to extract a query parameter in a print request in a QGIS Layout. But I did not find a way to do so (or any similar example).

Let's say I have following URL:

```
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=D:\QgisProjects\PRINT.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&CRS=EPSG:2056&TEMPLATE=A4&map0:EXTENT=2611694.6699335896,1266633.5855687414,2612170.3701136834,1267284.5437099217&map0:SCALE=2500&LAYERS=VW_STRASSE,VW_LS_LAERMBESCHWERDE,VW_LS_LAERMQUELLE,VW_BK_BOHRUNG&OPACITIES=128,204,153,204&title=TEST
```

I added a supplementary query parameter `title` at the end. I would like to pick this parameter up in the Print Layout of QGIS to fill a text field. (This should allow the user to specify the title of a downloaded PDF from a print file for example. Not the name of the pdf file itself, I mean inside the generated PDF).

Is there an actual way of doing this and get the value in the Expression-Builder window?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has already the [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) library on board. It includes the submodule [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) with two methods:

- [`urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) for parsing an URL
- [`parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) for parsing a query string

So, one can make use of it like this:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

URL = "http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=D:\QgisProjects\PRINT.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&CRS=EPSG:2056&TEMPLATE=A4&map0:EXTENT=2611694.6699335896,1266633.5855687414,2612170.3701136834,1267284.5437099217&map0:SCALE=2500&LAYERS=VW_STRASSE,VW_LS_LAERMBESCHWERDE,VW_LS_LAERMQUELLE,VW_BK_BOHRUNG&OPACITIES=128,204,153,204&title=TEST"

# parced URL
parsed_url = urlparse(URL)
query_in_url = parsed_url.query # extract the query
print(query_in_url)
""" results in :
map=D:\QgisProjects\PRINT.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&CRS=EPSG:2056&TEMPLATE=A4&map0:EXTENT=2611694.6699335896,1266633.5855687414,2612170.3701136834,1267284.5437099217&map0:SCALE=2500&LAYERS=VW_STRASSE,VW_LS_LAERMBESCHWERDE,VW_LS_LAERMQUELLE,VW_BK_BOHRUNG&OPACITIES=128,204,153,204&title=TEST
"""

# parced query
parced_query = parse_qs(query_in_url)
title_in_url = parced_query["title"] # extract the title
print(title_in_url[0]) # extract the title value
""" results in :
TEST
"""
```

This code can be converted into a function by means of the [Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor) to be able to return the title in Print Layout:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def extract_attr_name(URL, attr_name, feature, parent):
    """
    Extracts an attribute from a query embedded into an URL
    """

    # parced URL
    parsed_url = urlparse(URL)
    query_in_url = parsed_url.query # extract the query

    # parced query
    parced_query = parse_qs(query_in_url)
    title_in_url = parced_query[attr_name] # extract the title
    
    return title_in_url[0]
```

And then use it like this:

```py
extract_attr_name('http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=D:\QgisProjects\PRINT.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&CRS=EPSG:2056&TEMPLATE=A4&map0:EXTENT=2611694.6699335896,1266633.5855687414,2612170.3701136834,1267284.5437099217&map0:SCALE=2500&LAYERS=VW_STRASSE,VW_LS_LAERMBESCHWERDE,VW_LS_LAERMQUELLE,VW_BK_BOHRUNG&OPACITIES=128,204,153,204&title=TEST', 'title')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding a blank text box to your layout where you expect the title to be rendered. This textbox needs an ID. This can be set in the item properties "Item ID" part a little lower. Once this is set, you can pass the title text by this ID as parameter in the getprint url. The text you set will be shown on the print template.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression to get the output `TEST` from your example URL. Replace `@input` with the input string (your URL):

```
substr (@input, regexp_match (@input,'(&title=)')+7,9)
```

This replaces `(...)&title=TEST` with `TEST` (where `(...)` stands for any number of characters).

Explanation: using [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-match), you get the postion of the first matching of the string `&title=` in the input string: the postion of the character `&`. Add 7 to get the first character after `=`.

Then use [`substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#substr) to get the substring, starting at this position for a length of 9 (or whatever length you want).

*The upper part of the expression is the definition of the variable `@input`: the URL:*
[image]